# Arrange <mat-list-item> objects in <mat-list> automatically

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

The sample code:

```html
<div>
    <mat-list fxLayout="row" dense>
        <mat-list-item *ngFor="let label of labelsList"> <!-- just an array of strings -->
            <button mat-button>
                <mat-icon>cloud</mat-icon>
                {{label}}
            </button>
        </mat-list-item>
    </mat-list>
</div>
```

---

The result:
[image: Initial result]

---

When I resize the browser window:
[image: Result of mat-list after resize]

---

**What I need:** the buttons that don't "have room" to simply go on the next row.

How do I achieve this? I tried several combinations of CSS classes, properties, etc... nothing worked.

LATER EDIT: here's a complete reproducible example: https://angular-svt72k.stackblitz.io

Comment: Please add a complete and reproducible example, f.e. a StackBlitz to get you helped. Read also [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Roy here it is, correct link this time :) https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-svt72k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mat-list-item` is by default using the full width of its container and setting each item as `display: block`. To overrule this, you need to override the default Angular (Material) styling that comes with `<mat-list>`.

Setting `.mat-list-test` to `display: flex` and adding `flex-flow: row wrap` will make it go to the next line when there's not enough space available. Next to that, as said, the `.mat-list-item` styling is taking the full width. You can override it by setting `display: initial` and `width: auto`. Read more [about flexbox at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox).

#### CSS

```css
.mat-list-test {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.mat-list-base .mat-list-item.mat-list-item-test {
  display: initial;
  width: auto;
}
```

[image: Example of working mat-list]

See this [example on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ncwkyd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css) to show the outcome.

Comment: I used your code! my main issue is the <mat-list-item> not having the same text content so they will appear not aligned 
when I changed the width to  width: 50%; it's fine but the overlapping comes back ...
Any other suggestions?

Comment: @RebaiAhmed Please ask a new question.